# Why were there 13 Doctors prior to #12?

Tags: doctor-who

Thirteen Doctors encapsulated Gallifrey in *The Day of the Doctor*. But in *The Time of the Doctor* it mentioned 13 prior to his regeneration at the end of the episode. I count 12: #11 plus the War Doctor.

Where is the 13th Doctor?

Comment: But what about the curator who regenerated from the "War" doctor? I know that he was a special guest appearance from Tom Baker but doesn't he still technically count as another generation?

Comment: @KSB I've converted your 'answer' into a comment.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @KSB the War Doctor didn't regenerate into the Curator, he regenerated into the 9th Doctor (Eccleston). The Curator is supposed to be an incarnation of the Doctor in the far future, after he "retires".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The thirteen Doctors/TARDISes in *Day of the Doctor* don't map to the twelve regenerations that Eleven counts out in *Time of the Doctor.*

### The Twelfth Doctor makes an appearance in *The Day of the Doctor*.

Peter Capaldi's eyebrows have a cameo ("No, sir: all thirteen!") in *The Day of the Doctor*.

[image: Exhibit A: Capaldi's eyebrows]

So we get to see the First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth, Seventh, Eighth, Warth, Ninth, Tenth, Eleventh, and Twelfth Doctors whizzing about in their TARDISes.

### But *The Time of the Doctor* isn't counting Doctors; it's counting regenerations.

The Tenth Doctor was forced to regenerate in *The Stolen Earth* and *Journey's End*, but he used a trick to create the [Meta-Crisis Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Meta-Crisis_Tenth_Doctor) and keep his own face ("I had vanity issues").

[image: Ten cheats.]

This counts as a regeneration (but not a new Doctor) because it used up one of the packets of bio-energy Time Lords use to power their regenerations. The Meta-Crisis Doctor is largely human, doesn't have his own TARDIS to buzz around in (deleted scene debates notwithstanding), and is stuck in an alternate universe, so he doesn't count and didn't get invited to the saving-Gallifrey party.

Capaldi's Doctor doesn't get included in this regeneration count because at the time he hadn't happened yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the first section in your answer, but the second section answers it. Essentially 11 + War Doctor + Metacrisis Doctor = 13.

Comment: @Keavon Glad I can help; your question is a little complicated, and I hope my edits make it a bit clearer that the TARDISes in *Day of the Doctor* and the regeneration count in *Time of the Doctor* don't match up.

Comment: Much better. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: which merely leads to the flip-side of the question:  where were the *other* 12 future Doctors, since 11 got a whole new "regeneration cycle" to work with :)

Comment: There was a (deleted?) scene where the Meta Crisis Doctor is given a piece of TARDIS to grow his own from.  He's also off in another universe, which is why he wouldn't show up.

Comment: although, back then when the Time Lords were still around, apparently cross-universe travel was possible?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield The Doctor is a lone Time Lord with just a TARDIS available to him.  Gallifrey has much more powerful devices available on it, which enable all manner of whackiness that the Doctor alone can't manage simply due to his more limited resources.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield The answer to cross-universe travel is both simple and complicated, and could be worth its own question.

Comment: @Keen even if he did grow his own TARDIS, I think part of the idea of that scene is that *the same* TARDIS has been running that calculation for thousands of years, which is how they can make it work. Presumably meta-TARDIS wouldn't have been much help there.

Comment: The "Warth" Doctor. I like that!

Answer (score 4):

Capaldi is technically the 14th incarnation of The Doctor if you count Tennant staying the same from the Meta Crisis.  Matt Smith is supposed to be the 13th and final incarnation of The Doctor, which is why if he had died on Trenzalore that would have been his final resting place...

Now the reason they say all thirteen is because the Timelords on Gallifrey did not know that Tennant's doctor had used up a regeneration to stay the same so they would assume that the last doctor to show up, aka Capaldi, was the regeneration of Matt Smith using a new regeneration cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Meta crisis didn't get involved which means there's only the 1st, 2nd 3rd, 4th 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th (War), 10th (9th), 11th/12th (10th), 13th (11th), and 14th (12th Doctor, 14th incarnation, 13th face) versions of the Doctor. As someone said, the Meta Crisis didn't have his own TARDIS (they're supposed to take ages to grow anyway).

Answer (score 1):

No 13 Doctors — the 12th Doctor is the 12th *Doctor* but the 13th *regeneration*. Moffat said 11th was the 11th Doctor but on his 12th regeneration. Capaldi is part of the new regeneration cycle.

Quote from the Moffat himself:

> "He has no more ever called himself the 11th Doctor than he would call himself Matt Smith. The Doctor doesn't know off the top of his head [what number he is]. "If you worry about such things, and I do, then I specifically said John Hurt's Doctor doesn't use the title. [Matt Smith's Doctor] is in his 12th body but he's the 11th Doctor, however there is no such character as the 11th Doctor - he's just The Doctor, that's what he calls himself".

from this article:

http://www.blastr.com/2013-11-25/confused-moffat-addresses-all-those-who-regeneration-limit-questions

Comment: Except that Moffet has written shows where the Doctor has referred to himself by number (e.g. Matt Smith pointing to himself and going "number Eleven"), thus contradicting his own statements :(

Answer (score 0):

Matt Smith was confirmed to be the final incarnation of the Doctor in his original regeneration cycle. The War Doctor counts as one regeneration. The energy used by Tennant in Journey's End was a waste of a regeneration and counts. As Smith's Doctor says in Time of the Doctor. Of course, now things are even more complicated with Jodie Whittaker's recent series finale The Timeless Children where it is revealed the Doctor has infinite regenerations and is not originally from Gallifrey at all. The Doctor was found on another world as a young girl and her DNA was used by a greedy gallifreyan who not only passed on this ability to others on Gallifrey, but erased all memory of the past regenerations prior to William Hartnell. This woman also tortured the Doctor and made her regenerate many times to discover the secret of regeneration. I don't buy this though. Matt is the final incarnation  for the reasons I and others have given here.

Comment: You state a few things as fact here but don’t support them with evidence; could you [edit] in some in to back this up?